# A better way to get a ramtotal in busybox bin/sh?

Tags: grep, busybox, buildroot

So, something so simple, how much ram is installed in the current machine? I run a pxe image built in buildroot to grab system specifications from systems on a network boot. But, one thing seems to stick out to me. How do you effectively and reliably count the ram on every possible system.

I give you the worst code ever made, it's 6 years old and I am absolutely embarrassed by it.

```
ramtotal=0
ramsize=1
while test $ramsize -le 10000; do
ramcount=`dmidecode --type memory | grep -v Enabled | grep -v Installed | grep -v Maximum | grep "Size:" | grep "MB" | grep -c " $ramsize "`
ramup=$(( ramsize * ramcount ))
ramtotal=$(( ramtotal + ramup ))
ramsize=$(( ramsize * 2 ))
done
```

Well, may my code live long enough to be capable of counting ram chips with a size of 2^10000. Future proof ftw. And that's the thing, the code literally just worked, and so there was never any reason to make it disappear.

Today, I am trying a new code which worked fine on my Ubuntu Server, but not with busybox.

```
ramtotal=`dmidecode --type memory | grep -v Enabled | grep -v Installed | grep -v Maximum | grep "Size:" | grep "MB" | grep -o -P '(?<=\:\ ).*(?=\ MB)' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'`
```

Comment: I'm guessing by 'not working' you mean that the last grep is failing as it's busybox grep and not gnu grep. busybox grep does not support perl-style regexes. The line looks like `Size: NNNN MB` so convert it to `grep -o ' [0-9]* '` or maybe `awk '{print $2}'`?

Comment: If you are [using Awk anyway, you don't need `grep`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: Ahh, okay that makes sense. I assumed it was the awk failing that line. Nope, just the fancy grep usage?

Answer (score 0):

```
ramtotal=`dmidecode -t memory | grep "Size:" | awk '/Size: ([0-9]+) bytes|([kKMGTPEZ]B)/ {if($3 ~ /GB/) { size+=$2*1024 } else if($3 ~ /MB/) { size+=$2 } } END { print size }'`
```

So, it's been a long time since I originally posted. And I guess just to be consistent, I wanted to come back and update this, seeing as a change in the source code of dmidecode essentially breaks what I had previously added. Essentially for some reason dmidecode decided that this field could be MB or GB. (and perhaps something even bigger, though I didn't bother to research how forward thinking they decided to be).